# My first experience with gym environment has raised many questions, and I need some guidance

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning, gym, frozen-lake

As I'm new to the AI/ML field, I'm still learning from various online materials. In this particular instance, I've been studying the [Reinforcement Learning tutorial by deeplizard](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZbbT5o_s2xoWNVdDudn51XM8lOuZ_Njv&si=Ck2fqwB6CXttv8L9), specifically focusing on videos 8 through 10.

After attempting to replicate the example that demonstrates how to train an agent in the gym's FrozenLake environment, I encountered some unexpected issues. Although I successfully debugged the code and got the algorithm to work, I can't confidently claim that I fully comprehend if this is the correct approach. Therefore, I have specific questions related to this exercise that I intend to post within this single thread. Please feel free to answer any of the questions at your convenience.

## Q1

**What is this `gym` environment warning all about, and how should it be properly addressed?**

```
/home/boris/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gym/utils/passive_env_checker.py:233: DeprecationWarning: `np.bool8` is a deprecated alias for `np.bool_`.  (Deprecated NumPy 1.24)
  if not isinstance(terminated, (bool, np.bool8)):
```

So far, I've discovered two methods to handle this warning: One is to simply  suppress the warning as follows:

```
from warnings import filterwarnings
filterwarnings(action='ignore', category=DeprecationWarning, message='`np.bool8` is a deprecated alias')
```

Another is to replace the `gym` environment with the `gymnasium` environment, which does not produce this warning.

```
#import gym
import gymnasium as gym
```

This brings me to my second question.

## Q2

**Why are there two environments, `gym` and `gymnasium`, that do the same thing?**
Most online examples use `gym`, but I believe `gymnasium` is a better choice. Am I mistaken?

## Q3

**What's the distinction between "terminated" and "truncated"?** I've made numerous attempts, but I couldn't find a situation where they diverge. They consistently evaluate to either both True or both False.

In the current 'gym' version, I have to use "FrozenLake-v1" (originally, "FrozenLake-v0" was used in the tutorial), and this modification causes the code to break because the environment now expects 5 values instead of 4. Initially, I fixed this issue as follows:

```
new_state, reward, done, UNKNOWN, info = env.step(action)
```

I discovered later that the correct name for this variable is "truncated." Consequently, I adjusted the code as follows:

```
new_state, reward, terminated, truncated, info = env.step(action)
done = terminated or truncated
```

Nonetheless, I remain perplexed regarding the usage of "terminated" and "truncated." While experimenting with various algorithm options, such as `max_steps_per_episode`, I was unable to get them to differ. In all cases, they either both evaluate to True or both to False.

## Q4

**If I want to continue training the agent in stages and test its intermediate performance, how can I do that?** I was thinking it's just a matter of saving the q_table, then loading the saved q_table and replacing the current q_table initialization with the new one before resuming training. Or is it not that simple?

```
saved_q_table = anydbm.open(filename, 'r')

#q_table = np.zeros((state_space_size, action_space_size))
q_table = pickle.loads(saved_q_table)
```

## Q5

**Is there a way to get some documentation or help about the environment?**

I'm seeking a resource that I can print and reference while coding to gain a better understanding of the environment's parameters. For instance, in scikit-learn, you can achieve this with the following code:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor
from pprint import pprint
pprint(KNeighborsRegressor().get_params())
```

Resulting in following output:

```
{'algorithm': 'auto',
 'leaf_size': 30,
 'metric': 'minkowski',
 'metric_params': None,
 'n_jobs': None,
 'n_neighbors': 5,
 'p': 2,
 'weights': 'uniform'}
```

It would be great if one could get relevant agent/states parameters from the `gym` environments in a similar way.

## Q6

**How to use `render_mode="human"` correctly?** Currently, I'm using `render_mode="ansi"` and rendering the environment as follows:

```
env = gym.make("FrozenLake-v1", map_name="8x8", is_slippery=True, render_mode="ansi", desc=None)

print("\033c")
env.render()
print(env.render())
```

However, when I switch to `render_mode="human"`, the environment automatically displays without the need for env.render(). Consequently, the environment renders during training as well, leading to extremely slow training. How can I disable this automatic rendering when using render_mode="human"?

## Q7

**Why doesn't this algorithm work for an 8x8 map size?**

```
env = gym.make("FrozenLake-v1", map_name="8x8", is_slippery=True, render_mode="ansi", desc=None)
```

It appears that the agent is being trained, but it fails to learn anything.

```
*** Average reward per thousand episodes ***

1000 :  0.0
2000 :  0.0
3000 :  0.0
4000 :  0.0
5000 :  0.0
6000 :  0.0
7000 :  0.0
8000 :  0.0
9000 :  0.0
10000 :  0.0
```

I can't seem to figure out what needs to be modified. The `q_table` is the correct size:

```
q_table = np.zeros((state_space_size, action_space_size))
```

I've also increased `max_steps_per_episode` to 3000. Is it possible that `num_episodes = 10000` isn't sufficient?

## By the way, here is the full code I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np
#import gym
import gymnasium as gym
import random
import time
from warnings import filterwarnings

#filterwarnings(action='ignore', category=DeprecationWarning, message='`np.bool8` is a deprecated alias')

env = gym.make("FrozenLake-v1", map_name="4x4", is_slippery=True, render_mode="ansi", desc=None)
#env = gym.make("FrozenLake-v1", map_name="4x4", is_slippery=True, render_mode="human", desc=None)

action_space_size = env.action_space.n
state_space_size = env.observation_space.n
#print(action_space_size)
#print(state_space_size)

q_table = np.zeros((state_space_size, action_space_size))

num_episodes = 10000
max_steps_per_episode = 3000

learning_rate = 0.11
discount_rate = 0.99

exploration_rate = 1
max_exploration_rate = 0.99
min_exploration_rate = 0.01
exploration_decay_rate = 0.002

rewards_all_episodes = []

# Q-Learnig Algorithm
for episode in range(num_episodes):
    print("*** Episode ",  episode+1, " ***", end="\r")
    state = env.reset()[0]

    done = False
    rewards_current_episode = 0

    for step in range(max_steps_per_episode):

        # Exploration-Exploitation Trade-off
        exploration_rate_threshold = random.uniform(0, 1)
        if exploration_rate_threshold > exploration_rate:
            action = np.argmax(q_table[state, :])
        else:
            action = env.action_space.sample()
        new_state, reward, terminated, truncated, info = env.step(action)
        done = terminated or truncated

        # Update Q-Table for Q(s,a)
        q_table[state, action] = q_table[state, action] * (1 - learning_rate) + learning_rate * (reward + discount_rate * np.max(q_table[new_state, :]))

        state = new_state
        rewards_current_episode += reward

        if done == True:
            break

    # Exploration rate decay
    exploration_rate = min_exploration_rate + (max_exploration_rate - min_exploration_rate) * np.exp(-exploration_decay_rate * episode)

    rewards_all_episodes.append(rewards_current_episode)

# Calsulate and print the average reward per thousand episodes
rewards_per_thousand_episodes = np.split(np.array(rewards_all_episodes), num_episodes/1000)
count = 1000
print("*** Average reward per thousand episodes ***\n")
for r in rewards_per_thousand_episodes:
    print(count, ": ", str(sum(r/1000)))
    count += 1000

# Print updated Q-Table
print("\n\n*** Updated Q-Table ***\n")
print(q_table)
input("Press Enter to continue...")

num_episodes = 5
max_steps_per_episode = 99

for episode in range(num_episodes):
    state = env.reset()[0]

    done = False

    for step in range(max_steps_per_episode):
        print("\033c")
        print("*** Episode ",  episode+1, " ***\n", step)
        env.render()
        print(env.render())
        time.sleep(0.1)

        action = np.argmax(q_table[state, :])
        new_state, reward, done, unknown, info = env.step(action)

        # Update Q-Table for Q(s,a)
        q_table[state, action] = q_table[state, action] * (1 - learning_rate) + learning_rate * (reward + discount_rate * np.max(q_table[new_state, :]))

        state = new_state
        rewards_current_episode += reward

        if done == True:
            print("\033c")
            print("*** Episode ",  episode+1, " ***\n")
            env.render()
            print(env.render())
            if reward == 1:
                print("*** You reached the goal! ***")
                time.sleep(3)
            else:
                print("*** You fell through a hole! ***")
                time.sleep(3)
            #clear_output(wait=True)
            break

        if step == max_steps_per_episode - 1:
            print("*** You failed to complete the task! ***")
            time.sleep(3)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Q1. What is this gym environment warning all about, and how should it be properly addressed?

The development of `gym` has ended I think. Anyway the error is about an old usage of `numpy`, so probably you have installed a newer version of it.

> Q2. Why are there two environments, gym and gymnasium, that do the same thing?

In principle, they do the same thing but `gym` was developed by OpenAI and `gymnasium` by Farama Foundation, which inherited `gym` basically. You should use `gymnasium` from now on, since is in actual development. This means that initially `gym` and `gymnasium` were almost identical but now their are diverging, even if the underlying concepts are still the same.

> Q3. What's the distinction between "terminated" and "truncated"?

`truncated` indicates that the episode ended due to a time limit, i.e. the current timestep have exceeded the time limit so the episode ends. This also indicated that you have to *bootstrap* the Q value estimate.

`terminated` instead is when the agent have reached a terminal state, therefore the episode naturally ends. You should use both to understand when an episode terminates, e.g. `if truncated or terminated: ...`, but the two flags are useful to determine when or not to bootstrap: you don't do that on termination, for example.

> Q4. If I want to continue training the agent in stages and test its intermediate performance, how can I do that?

You need to save the Q-table (or, in general, the weights/parameters of a function approximator like a neural-net) but also the current value of the `episilon` (if using some schedule, so if changing during the episodes) and similar. Then you instantiate the agent, load the various parameters, and continue training where you left.

> Q5. Is there a way to get some documentation or help about the environment?

Try `help(env)`, the official website (https://gymnasium.farama.org/index.html), or read the env's source code.

> Q6. How to use render_mode="human" correctly?

If you set `render_mode="human"` gymnasium will render at each `step()` and even `reset()`: this is something that `gym` not used to do.

I'm not sure but you may need to wrap the env with this `gymnasium.wrappers.RenderCollection` ([docs](https://gymnasium.farama.org/api/wrappers/misc_wrappers/#gymnasium.wrappers.RenderCollection)) to trigger the rendering only when `render()` is called - I haven't tested that, so I can be wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot! To summarize,
 / - `gymnasium` environments are the way to go
 / - `help(env)` prints documentation about environment
 / - need to learn about bootstrapping the Q value estimate to use `truncated` flag
 / - to resume training need both Q-table and epsilon value
 / - check `gymnasium.wrappers` for advanced rendering options

Comment: @BorisL. Yeah, that's all you need to do and know in short. Also bootstrapping is something you'll find in Q-learning and TD-learning. I think there is some good answer about it, in AI SE.